# How to implement caching on IdentityServer4?

Tags: identityserver4

How to implement **cache for ClientStore** in IdSrv4? I'm already checking the docs at [AddClientStoreCache](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/startup.html?highlight=AddClientStoreCache)
but it does not help me...
On my *ConfigureServices* method i'm configuring IdSrv as follows:

```cs
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.IssuerUri = "http://idp.address.jus.br/";
            options.Caching.ClientStoreExpiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
        })
        .AddSigningCredential(cert)
        .AddClientStoreCache<ClientStore>();
```

...And in my *ClientStore* implementation i do not have anything about caching...Should i check wheter the info is on cache in *FindClientByIdAsync* in some way? Or its done for me under the hood?

I found a sample only at [IdentityServer4.Postgresql](https://github.com/Sphiecoh/IdentityServer4.Postgresql/tree/master/src/IdentityServer4.Postgresql), but i can't replicate it with sucess on my custom *Store* classes...

Comment: What do you mean by caching? Saving the `clients`, `access_tokens` in a database?

Comment: IdrSrv has options for caching of ClientStore and ResourceStore, but there is any sample of it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for a sample implementation of the `CachingClientStore.cs`, you could check out the default implementation (the way the identity server does this) [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/0b213f3307d9dc14e66e8d5fafefe6405ff52f74/src/IdentityServer4/Stores/Caching/CachingClientStore.cs).

```cs
public async Task<Client> FindClientByIdAsync(string clientId)
{
     var client = await _cache.GetAsync(clientId,
     _options.Caching.ClientStoreExpiration,
     () => _inner.FindClientByIdAsync(clientId),
     _logger);

     return client;
}
```

They are giving you the choice how to implement your caching algorithm. You could cache the ClientStore in a In-Memory database such as Redis. The good thing about IdentityServer4 is you can implement the interfaces however you want and however you need them.

Answer (score 2):

`AddConfigurationStoreCache()` via https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/host/Startup.cs#L47

Comment: Here's an updated link to the function itself: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/EntityFramework/src/IdentityServerEntityFrameworkBuilderExtensions.cs#L63

Answer (score 1):

I know that this topic is a bit old but I found my solution which might help somebody. So you just need to add the following code to the **startup.cs**

```
using IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Services;
using IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores;

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services
   .AddIdentityServer(options =>
   {
      options.Caching.ClientStoreExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
      options.Caching.ResourceStoreExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
      options.Caching.CorsExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
      //other options
   })
   .AddInMemoryCaching()
   .AddClientStoreCache<ClientStore>()
   .AddCorsPolicyCache<CorsPolicyService>()
   .AddConfigurationStoreCache()
   .AddResourceStoreCache<ResourceStore>()
   //other things
```

[Source](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/startup.html#caching)

Answer (score 0):

In startup.cs I just write:

```
     //Load user /password in runtime
            services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, DBResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();

///verify by clientid & client secrect in mssql 

services.AddTransient<IClientStore, DbClientStore>();
```

In DbClientStore.cs :

```
public class DbClientStore : IClientStore
    {
        IDNHClientsServices clientsService;
        protected IStaticCacheManager cacheManager ;
        public DbClientStore(IDNHClientsServices repository, IStaticCacheManager staticCacheManager)
        {
            clientsService = repository;
            cacheManager = staticCacheManager;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Dùng để get client secrect trong db trung quá trình runtime
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="clientId"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Task<Client> FindClientByIdAsync(string clientId)
        {
            
            ClientsResponse client = cacheManager.Get(string.Format("clientkey.{0}", clientId), () => clientsService.GetClientInfo(clientId).Result);
            if (client == null)
            {
                return Task.FromResult<Client>(null);
            }
           
            ICollection<string> type = null;
            switch (client.AllowedGrantTypes)
            {
                case GrantType.ResourceOwnerPassword:
                    type = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword;
                    break;
                case GrantType.ClientCredentials:
                    type = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials;
                    break;
                default:
                    type = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword;
                    break;
            }

            return Task.FromResult(new Client()
            {
                ClientId = client.clientId,
                AllowedGrantTypes = type,
                AllowedScopes = client.AllowedScopes,
                ClientSecrets = client.ClientSecrets
            });
        }
    }

public class ClientsResponse 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string clientId { get; set; }
    public string RedirectUris { get; set; }
    public string AllowedGrantTypes { get; set; }
    public bool Enable { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> AllowedScopes { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Secret> ClientSecrets { get; set; }
}
```