# Cache Identityserver user

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, .net-6.0

when I use TestUser in dunde.identityserver the performance is excellent, which is normal, but when I use ApplicationUser and read the information from SQL server, the performance decreases a lot. Is there any way for caching the Applicationuser?

Comment: Our great frien Redis can help a lot

Answer (score 1):

There are several built-in options and third-party caching options for IdentityServer.

Some starting points are:

- [Caching Configuration Data](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/reference/di/#caching-configuration-data)
- [IdentityServer4.Contrib.Caching](https://github.com/alsami/IdentityServer4.Contrib.Caching)
- [How to implement caching on IdentityServer4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43858231/how-to-implement-caching-on-identityserver4)